# What is the difference between SolrIndexedProperty and SolrIndexedType?

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm new to the Solr concept. I know that values are stored in key-value pairs in Solr, but there are so many things which are confusing in the `solr.impex`.

I wanted to know the clear use of the words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `SolrIndexedType`, you defined the type (e.g. Product type) to be indexed.

In `SolrIndexedProperty`, you define the attributes of the type (e.g. code, name, and description of Product) that you want to index. Here, define the type (e.g. string, boolean) of the attribute, how it will be indexed into Solr, and some other attributes.

Comment: So if I want to index my new item type I can use solrIndexedType. If I want to index the attribute of my new item type I can use solrIndexedProperty.

Comment: @vinaymore If you need more documentation about configuring the SolrIndexedType and SolrIndexedProperty, you can check this out - https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/bc912462e6974ac596b252cd18680e4e.html#loiobc912462e6974ac596b252cd18680e4e - assuming you have access to Hybris Help.